# How to retrieve the text of an element and write it to a file for later retrieval in protractor using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xpath, protractor

So, I have to check the status of an action started by the automation script using another automation script. In order to track the action, I have to capture its Id and write it to a file which can be then read by the second script to look for the action. The problem I am having is that I am unable to get the action Id which is a number using getText(). Instead, I keep seeing other non sensical text when I check the content of the file or the variable to which I first store the Id.

The html code for action Id is:

```
<dd class="ng-binding">232</dd>
```

I am trying to capture the Id (#232 here) like this:

```
var Id = element(by.xpath('html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/dl/dd[1]')).getText();
```

Upon executing the automation script, the console output shows this for the var Id:

```
Id:[object Object]
```

I have verified using protractor elementExplorer that xpath points to the right element and can even extract the Id and displays it on the screen correctly. It just does not work when I am trying to store the same Id to a variable and then write to a file so that I can retrieve it for later use. Any help or hints on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getText()` returns a promise, you have to resolve it, using absolute xpath is a bad way of locating elements. Have you tried locating with `cssSelector`?

```
  element(by.css('dd.ng-binding')).getText().then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
  });
```

Comment: Ok, that worked. I did not realize getText() returns a promise. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `ng-binding` is a poor locator choice as well - it does not bring any information about the element and is a pure technical angular class.

Comment: @alecxe ya sometimes it works but not reliable, i just wanted to give an example with css :)